# simplexml with curl to get a formatted xml call back with api

Tags: php, xml, curl

Ok, so I am getting an api call from my re sellers panel for hosting. What I am trying to do is achieve this for my countries:

```
<select name="countries">
  <option value="n226">United States</option>
</select>
```

Where value is equal to the tag name and the display is equal to the name for each country.

I am currently using Curl and the simplexml_load_string php code.

```
function test() {

  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "ApiCallUrl");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, POST);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  $string = curl_exec($ch);   

  $xml = simplexml_load_string($string);

  print_r($xml);
}
```

What I have above returns what it is supposed to return (in a slightly jumbled mess)

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
( [command] => 0 [error_code] => 0 [ttl] => 56000 [countries] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [n0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [name] => Afghanistan [iso2] => AF [phone_code] => 93 )
    [n1] =&gt; SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [name] =&gt; Albania
            [iso2] =&gt; AL
            [phone_code] =&gt; 355
        )
```

In short that is what it returns currently.

Now when I change `print_r($xml);` to `print_r($xml->name);` as suggested in example one on the php website: http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php it only returns: `SimpleXMLElement Object ( )` with nothing else.

Right now I am just trying to echo out the name of each country, I'm not necessarily worried about the select right now.

So why would it work with: `print_r($xml);` but not with `print_r($xml->name);`

BTW:

Before I do anything with the api, It displays the following: (I achieved this by adding `print_r($string);` directly after defining $string

```
<ampa>
<command></command>0
<error_code>0</error_code>
<ttl>56000</ttl>
<countries>
    <n0>
        <name>Afghanistan</name>
        <iso2>AF</iso2>
        <phone_code>93</phone_code>
    </n0>
    <n1>
        <name>Albania</name>
        <iso2>AL</iso2>
        <phone_code>355</phone_code>
    </n1>
```

Comment: The basic examples are here: http://php.net/simplexml.examples-basic - use those to get a step the first steps into SimpleXML, `print_r` and `var_dump` are lying with SimpleXML (sort-of) ;), instead use `$xml->asXML('php://output');` and view source in your browser (or plain text content-type)