# registerXPathNamespace on xml file with multiple urls

Tags: php, xpath

I am trying to get the following thing to work, but all i get as a result is an empty array. With cURL i am recieving an XML result, which i try to access using xpath.

After reading the example on php.net aswell as on others sites, i came up with the PHP code below, however all examples i could find use a very basic xml file with only one url, whist mine has two urls. I assume i have to use the last url since that is the one binding the content.

```
<?PHP
function download_page($path)
{
    $postData = 'requestXml=<bericht>
                                <authenticatie>
                                    <naam>XXXXX</naam>
                                    <wachtwoord>XXXXX</wachtwoord>
                                    <berichtsoort>SB-RDW-ADVANCED</berichtsoort>
                                </authenticatie>
                                <parameters>
                                    <kenteken>42pzks</kenteken>
                                </parameters>
                            </bericht>';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $path);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 300);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);

    $retValue = curl_exec($ch);          
    curl_close($ch);

    return $retValue;
}

$sXML = download_page('https://acceptatie-interdata.vwe.nl/DataAanvraag.asmx/standaardDataRequest');
$oXML = new SimpleXMLElement($sXML);

$oXML->registerXPathNamespace('c', 'http://www.xmlmode.nl/interdata/rdw');
$result = $oXML->xpath('//c:handelsbenaming');

echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

The XML has the following result

```
<antwoordbericht xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<aanvraag>
    <bericht>
        <authenticatie>
            <naam>XXX</naam>
            <wachtwoord>XXX</wachtwoord>
            <berichtsoort>SB-RDW-ADVANCED</berichtsoort>
        </authenticatie>
        <parameters>
            <kenteken>42pzks</kenteken>
        </parameters>
    </bericht>
</aanvraag>
<resultaat>
    <code>00</code>
    <omschrijving>Ok</omschrijving>
    <interdataReferentie>985933</interdataReferentie>
</resultaat>
<rubrieken>
    <rdwInfoAdvanced xsi:type="rdw:rdwInfoAdvancedTypeV4" xmlns:rdw="http://www.xmlmode.nl/interdata/rdw">
        <rdw:kenteken>42PZKS</rdw:kenteken>
        <rdw:isMeldCodeCorrect>false</rdw:isMeldCodeCorrect>
        <rdw:kentekenSignaal xsi:nil="true" />
        <rdw:merk code="BMWP">bmw</rdw:merk>
        <rdw:handelsbenaming>5ER REIHE; 525D TOURING AUT.</rdw:handelsbenaming>
        <rdw:voertuigsoort>P</rdw:voertuigsoort>
        <rdw:brandstof1 code="D">diesel</rdw:brandstof1>
        <rdw:brandstof2 xsi:nil="true" />
        <rdw:kleur1 code="07">grijs</rdw:kleur1>
        <rdw:kleur2 code="99">niet van toepassing</rdw:kleur2>
        <rdw:aantalZitplaatsen>5</rdw:aantalZitplaatsen>
        <rdw:aantalStaanplaatsen>0</rdw:aantalStaanplaatsen>
        <rdw:datumEersteToelatingInternationaal>2005-03-04</rdw:datumEersteToelatingInternationaal>
        <rdw:datumEersteToelatingNationaal>2005-03-04</rdw:datumEersteToelatingNationaal>
        <rdw:datumAansprakelijkheid>2010-02-23</rdw:datumAansprakelijkheid>
        <rdw:datumVervalApk>2013-12-31</rdw:datumVervalApk>
        <rdw:aantalCilinders>6</rdw:aantalCilinders>
        <rdw:cilinderinhoud>2497</rdw:cilinderinhoud>
        <rdw:massaLeegVoertuig>1660</rdw:massaLeegVoertuig>
        <rdw:laadvermogen>0</rdw:laadvermogen>
        <rdw:maximumMassa>2285</rdw:maximumMassa>
        <rdw:massaRijklaar>1760</rdw:massaRijklaar>
        <rdw:maximumMassaOngeremd>750</rdw:maximumMassaOngeremd>
        <rdw:maximumMassaGeremd>2000</rdw:maximumMassaGeremd>
        <rdw:maximumMassaOpleggerGeremd>0</rdw:maximumMassaOpleggerGeremd>
        <rdw:maximumMassaAutonoomGeremd>0</rdw:maximumMassaAutonoomGeremd>
        <rdw:maximumMassaMiddenasGeremd>0</rdw:maximumMassaMiddenasGeremd>
        <rdw:parallelImport>false</rdw:parallelImport>
        <rdw:uitvoeringsVolgnummer>22500</rdw:uitvoeringsVolgnummer>
        <rdw:aantalDeuren>4</rdw:aantalDeuren>
        <rdw:inrichting code="44">stationwagen</rdw:inrichting>
        <rdw:voertuigClassificatie code="01">personenauto</rdw:voertuigClassificatie>
        <rdw:aantalWielen>4</rdw:aantalWielen>
        <rdw:vermogenKw>130</rdw:vermogenKw>
        <rdw:vermogenBromfiets xsi:nil="true" />
        <rdw:maximaleConstructiesnelheid>0</rdw:maximaleConstructiesnelheid>
        <rdw:emissieCode>R</rdw:emissieCode>
        <rdw:g3Installatie>false</rdw:g3Installatie>
        <rdw:bpm>19775</rdw:bpm>
        <rdw:verplichtingennemer>false</rdw:verplichtingennemer>
        <rdw:wamVerzekerd>true</rdw:wamVerzekerd>
        <rdw:wielbasis>288</rdw:wielbasis>
        <rdw:motorcode>256D2</rdw:motorcode>
        <rdw:catalogusPrijs xsi:nil="true" />
        <rdw:isTaxi>false</rdw:isTaxi>
    </rdwInfoAdvanced>
</rubrieken>
```

The result i recieve before applying the simplexml element is:

```
<antwoordbericht xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<aanvraag>
    &lt;bericht&gt; 
        &lt;authenticatie&gt; 
            &lt;naam&gt;XXXX&lt;/naam&gt; 
            &lt;wachtwoord&gt;XXXX&lt;/wachtwoord&gt; 
            &lt;berichtsoort&gt;SB-RDW-ADVANCED&lt;/berichtsoort&gt; 
        &lt;/authenticatie&gt; 
        &lt;parameters&gt; 
            &lt;kenteken&gt;42pzks&lt;/kenteken&gt; 
        &lt;/parameters&gt; 
    &lt;/bericht&gt;
</aanvraag>
<resultaat>
    <code>00</code>
    <omschrijving>Ok</omschrijving>
    <interdataReferentie>987573</interdataReferentie>
</resultaat>
<rubrieken>
    <rdwInfoAdvanced xsi:type="rdw:rdwInfoAdvancedTypeV4" xmlns:rdw="http://www.xmlmode.nl/interdata/rdw">
        <rdw:kenteken>42PZKS</rdw:kenteken>
        <rdw:isMeldCodeCorrect>false</rdw:isMeldCodeCorrect>
        <rdw:kentekenSignaal xsi:nil="true" />
        <rdw:merk code="BMWP">bmw</rdw:merk>
        <rdw:handelsbenaming>5ER REIHE; 525D TOURING AUT.</rdw:handelsbenaming>
        <rdw:voertuigsoort>P</rdw:voertuigsoort>
        <rdw:brandstof1 code="D">diesel</rdw:brandstof1>
        <rdw:brandstof2 xsi:nil="true" />
        <rdw:kleur1 code="07">grijs</rdw:kleur1>
        <rdw:kleur2 code="99">niet van toepassing</rdw:kleur2>
        <rdw:aantalZitplaatsen>5</rdw:aantalZitplaatsen>
        <rdw:aantalStaanplaatsen>0</rdw:aantalStaanplaatsen>
        <rdw:datumEersteToelatingInternationaal>2005-03-04</rdw:datumEersteToelatingInternationaal>
        <rdw:datumEersteToelatingNationaal>2005-03-04</rdw:datumEersteToelatingNationaal>
        <rdw:datumAansprakelijkheid>2010-02-23</rdw:datumAansprakelijkheid>
        <rdw:datumVervalApk>2013-12-31</rdw:datumVervalApk>
        <rdw:aantalCilinders>6</rdw:aantalCilinders>
        <rdw:cilinderinhoud>2497</rdw:cilinderinhoud>
        <rdw:massaLeegVoertuig>1660</rdw:massaLeegVoertuig>
        <rdw:laadvermogen>0</rdw:laadvermogen>
        <rdw:maximumMassa>2285</rdw:maximumMassa>
        <rdw:massaRijklaar>1760</rdw:massaRijklaar>
        <rdw:maximumMassaOngeremd>750</rdw:maximumMassaOngeremd>
        <rdw:maximumMassaGeremd>2000</rdw:maximumMassaGeremd>
        <rdw:maximumMassaOpleggerGeremd>0</rdw:maximumMassaOpleggerGeremd>
        <rdw:maximumMassaAutonoomGeremd>0</rdw:maximumMassaAutonoomGeremd>
        <rdw:maximumMassaMiddenasGeremd>0</rdw:maximumMassaMiddenasGeremd>
        <rdw:parallelImport>false</rdw:parallelImport>
        <rdw:uitvoeringsVolgnummer>22500</rdw:uitvoeringsVolgnummer>
        <rdw:aantalDeuren>4</rdw:aantalDeuren><
        rdw:inrichting code="44">stationwagen</rdw:inrichting>
        <rdw:voertuigClassificatie code="01">personenauto</rdw:voertuigClassificatie>
        <rdw:aantalWielen>4</rdw:aantalWielen>
        <rdw:vermogenKw>130</rdw:vermogenKw>
        <rdw:vermogenBromfiets xsi:nil="true" />
        <rdw:maximaleConstructiesnelheid>0</rdw:maximaleConstructiesnelheid>
        <rdw:emissieCode>R</rdw:emissieCode>
        <rdw:g3Installatie>false</rdw:g3Installatie>
        <rdw:bpm>19775</rdw:bpm>
        <rdw:verplichtingennemer>false</rdw:verplichtingennemer>
        <rdw:wamVerzekerd>true</rdw:wamVerzekerd>
        <rdw:wielbasis>288</rdw:wielbasis>
        <rdw:motorcode>256D2</rdw:motorcode>
        <rdw:catalogusPrijs xsi:nil="true" />
        <rdw:isTaxi>false</rdw:isTaxi>
    </rdwInfoAdvanced>
</rubrieken>
```

Comment: Your PHP code and registering of namespace looks fine to me. Also the XPath seems OK to retrieve the node. Are you sure the response doesn't have more namespaces?

Comment: Looking at https://acceptatie-interdata.vwe.nl/DataAanvraag.asmx?WSDL. It seems like there are more namespaces in it. Like to soap namespace and the request/response namespace

Comment: Mark, i added the response i get before applying the simplexmlelement command.

Comment: You can retrieve the XPath `//code`?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? If i can do $result = $oXML->xpath('code');?

Comment: `$result = $oXML->xpath('//code');`. Would this produce any output?

Comment: It does not give any output

Comment: Then it looks like the PHP is not correct. When I look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19649116/simplexml-with-curl-to-get-a-formatted-xml-call-back-with-api It seems that maybe you need to change the code `$oXML = new SimpleXMLElement($sXML);` to `$oXML = simplexml_load_string($sXML);`

Comment: Well, i tried changing it to simplexml_load_string, that also did not give me any output. Than i tried asXML as given in a comment in your url, that gives me an error: Warning: SimpleXMLElement::asXML(//rdw:handelsbenaming) [simplexmlelement.asxml]: failed to open stream: Permission denied (i get the same error with //code)